# CSS & HTML how to stop linear-gradient from repeating vertically and horizontally on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

When I use pinch zoom and shrink the size of my webpage on a mobile device, the gradient repeats and I do not want it to. Is there anyway to stop this?

I would rather it resize the gradient as all of my other elements are dynamic and resize appropriately.

Here is my code so far:

```css
html {
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: auto;
  background: #33ccff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top right, #33ccff 0%, #0066ff 100%) no-repeat;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to top right, #33ccff 0%, #0066ff 100%) no-repeat;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(to top right, #33ccff 0%, #0066ff 100%) no-repeat;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #33ccff 0%, #0066ff 100%) no- repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
}

.off {
  color: #F0FFFF;
}

#header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 960px;
}

#header h1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 45px;
  left: 5px;
  top: 20px;
}

#navigationBar {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #F0FFFF;
  border-color: #000000;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#navigationMenu {
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #F0FFFF;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#transparentBox {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: max-width;
  height: max-height;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  filter: Alpha(opacity=0.7);
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Caleb<span class="off">Wolff</span></h1>
</div>

<div id="navigationBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.calebwolff.us">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/calebwolffmusic/" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/calebwolffmusic/" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/caleb-wolff-
    07594aab" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="transparentBox">
  <h1>Hello! Welcome to my website!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: this could be related to styling the html element. Try applying the background to a wrapper div, and set the size of that element to the viewport using vw and vh units (i.e. width: 100vw).

Comment: @corse32 I made the changes you suggested however it did not seem to have any impact on the mobile version of my page. You can see what I'm talking about by visiting calebwolff.us on your mobile browser.

Comment: hmmm ok, I can't zoom out on iOS safari so I'm unable to reproduce the issue here, sorry I can't help further!

Comment: @CalebWolff in your code you wrote ` no- repeat` this is incorrect, there a space between `-` and `repeat`.. it should be `no-repeat`

Comment: @Aziz I can't seem to find that anywhere. Where did you see that?

Comment: Oh! sorry @Aziz It is correct in my code, I must have screwed up transferring it to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you in all browsers. You were  using a combination of shorthand and other css properties that may have been cancelling each other out.

```css
html {
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #33ccff, #0066ff) no-repeat;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to top right, #33ccff, #0066ff) no-repeat;
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(to top right, #33ccff, #0066ff) no-repeat;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top right, #33ccff, #0066ff) no-repeat;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top right, #33ccff, #0066ff) no-repeat;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(to top right, #33ccff, #0066ff) no-repeat;
  background:  linear-gradient(to top right, #33ccff, #0066ff) no-repeat;  
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
}

.off {
  color: #F0FFFF;
}

#header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 960px;
}

#header h1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 45px;
  left: 5px;
  top: 20px;
}

#navigationBar {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #F0FFFF;
  border-color: #000000;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

#navigationMenu {
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #F0FFFF;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#transparentBox {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: max-width;
  height: max-height;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  filter: Alpha(opacity=0.7);
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Caleb<span class="off">Wolff</span></h1>
</div>

<div id="navigationBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.calebwolff.us">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/calebwolffmusic/" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/calebwolffmusic/" target="_blank">Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/caleb-wolff-
    07594aab" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="transparentBox">
  <h1>Hello! Welcome to my website!</h1>
</div>
```

I've tested on a mobile devices and it looks great.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it worked! Can you explain to me what the issue was? I'm new to HTML and CSS. (I develop in Python, Java, Objective-C, and a variety of other languages and I am just beginning to dabble with web dev.)

Comment: A few things, first as mentioned you had an extra space after the hyphen in the standard syntax for the background gradient. Also, you used shorthand for no-repeat in the background property, but also used the background-property itself in your declaration block. That's not very dry(http://vanseodesign.com/css/dry-principles/) CSS, and could have been causing the issue depending on the browser/device you're viewing with. Anyway, good luck with your site!

Comment: Thanks again, you've been very helpful!